# display two variables in a single column

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to display 2 fields value in same column one field datatype is formula with return type text to display the image and the other field is a picklist field. this is how it looks when i have separate column for each

[image]

When i use the following code to merge the column the formula field(graphical) displays the img url. something like this

```
<apex:column headerValue="Assigned To">
                    {!item.Assigned_Queue__c}<br></br>
                    {!item.Assigned_To__c}
</apex:column>
```

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Dis you try it without using html br tags? Check once without putting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `apex:outputText` and specify escape parameter as false.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!book.image_formula__c}" escape="false"/>
```

VF Page example

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" recordSetVar="books" >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!books}" var="book" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Assign To">
                <apex:outputText value="{!book.Country__c}" escape="false"/><br></br>
                <apex:outputText value="{!book.image_formula__c}" escape="false"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @sfdcconsultant  Please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question, so other users can find it useful!